# How to send variables using exec() PHP

Tags: php, command-line

I am trying to send php variables to a function, but none of the following are passing the variables.

```
$vars='email=' . $_POST['email'] . '&password=' . $_POST['password'] . '&server=' . $_POST['server'];
$function = 'nohup php unsubscribefunction.php ' . escapeshellarg($vars);
exec($function); 
exec('nohup php unsubscribefunction.php ' . $vars);
exec('nohup php unsubscribefunction.php $vars ');


$vars='?email=' . $_POST['email'] . '&password=' . $_POST['password'] . '&server=' . $_POST['server'];
$function = 'nohup php unsubscribefunction.php' . $vars;
exec($function);
```

**Here's what [the php.net page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) says about this**

> When allowing user-supplied data to be
>   passed to this function, use
>   escapeshellarg() or escapeshellcmd()
>   to ensure that users cannot trick the
>   system into executing arbitrary
>   commands.

However, there are no examples on how to pass the variables, any insights or examples would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason why you have to call another PHP script to the background from the PHP script you're already using?

Comment: Yes, long story, I'm building this for the 50%+ of my users who don't have javascript enabled.  I need to do a page refresh for users who don't have javascript enabled.  So without javascript, I need to call the function in the background using exec and then refresh to a page that tells users their search has successfully started.  (I love javascript...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reading through some of the help [here](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/command-line-arguments-php-cli/). Basically, you will need to make sure you are consuming the command line vars through `$argc`/`getopt()` or some other fashion.

Call the script with flags, like so: `php myscript.php -a foo -b bar -c baz`
Test print your arguments:

```
   <?php
           $arguments = getopt("a:b:c:");
           print_r($arguments);
    ?>
Array
(
    [a] => foo
    [b] => bar
    [c] => baz
)
```

Comment: Thanks - I was able to get this work - only issue is that it's not performing in the background when I use "nohup php" before the commands - any insight in what i'd need to change so this would run in the background and allow the next page to load?

Comment: $vars = escapeshellcmd($_POST['email']) . " " . escapeshellcmd($_POST['password']) . " " . escapeshellcmd($_POST['server']);
exec("nohup php unsubscribefunction.php " . $vars);
header('Location:  http://location.php');

Comment: Try something along these lines: `exec(sprintf("%s > %s 2>&1 & echo $! >> %s", $cmd, $outputfile, $pidfile));` where $cmd is your command AND arguments as one variable, $outputfile is a file to store output from your second script and $pidfile is a file to store the process id of the script you're kicking off. This of course, is assuming you are on a Linux/Unix based machine.

Answer (score 1):

That's not the problem you're having. You can't send variables this way; you need to use [command line arguments](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) to capture the values you want to put in variables.

Comment: What would be the call in that case? and how would I use nohup to run it in the background?